# PHP extension build system

Tags: php, c++

this is a first time when I faced with a building PHP extension. I see there is some build system based on config.m4 and config.w32 for linux and windows respectively. any reason to use this instead of industrial standard cmake? this is the dll/so, isn't it? so I already have a project based on cmake, and used in other places. For PHP, I've added required by Zend interfaces, rebuild this and add the setting to load this by Zend. which place where I potentially require to use m4 or w32 configs?

Comment: The reason is that it was implemented before cmake became "industrial standard" (in quotes because it is not true)